Monocular odometry Python systematic error
I'm trying to develop a program that will estimate trajectory using monocular odometry. The problem is I receive unpredictable results: for example, when I use static image, it shows false trajectory with sistematic error - every next frame increasing or decreasing both coordinates for near-to-same value (something from 0.8-1 each frame). Can provide data and plotting results if needed.
I forked from Jasleon Github project, where made script that gave me results from example in Readme course. Here I have my program (wrote from Jasleon course guide).
I can't receive normal results and don't get a problem.
What I thought is that by copying algorithms I could get ready-to-use results. Of course, I tried to develop my own program (but maths and base princips are the same).
The problem shouldn't be in calibration: I tried different methods - Python program calibration (a few tries), Matlab toolbox calibration. Resulting constants are similar in different methods. I also wrote a program that checks calibration results and it's working well - the image converting definitely the same as in description of this process.
Also I tried to make a video from Jasleon dataset and then work with received frames. It also gave me a same mistake that I described in problem and that I received in every my try.
And I tried different cameras and video angels - it didnt work for me.

you forked some random github repo? then contact the author first. -- [mre] required. pointing at someone's github is not a MRE
